# Text to speech software

Tags: text-to-speech-voices

Looking for a text to speech software that pops out a window that contains the text as it reads out the text.
I remember one software having such a functionality, speaky. However, it doesn't seem to be available now.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NeuroSpeech [**ClipBoard Speaker**](http://www.neurospeech.com/Products/ClipBoardSpeaker.html) might suit your needs.

> Select and Copy Text – CBSpeaker
>   Automatically Reads it out loud.
>
> Different voices to suit your taste.

and here's another (very basic) freebie:

**[Clipboard Speaker](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Office-tools/Clipboard/Clipboard-Speaker.shtml)** allows user to play content copied into clipboard. Simply specify the text, and you will be able to immediately hear it (Clipboard Speaker is a tiny, portable application, just unzip and run).

[image]

for large documents and more complex tasks such as MP3 export i'm using [**Cool Reader 2**](http://coolreader.org/e-index.htm).

just load the text from file into CR2 and hit **Enter** to toggle ReadAloud (TTS) on/off or **F2** export to MP3.

supported formats:  TXT, RTF, DOC, HTML and FB2 (even archived as RAR, ZIP, HA, ARJ or LHA)

CoolReader 2 is free and portable (doesn't require installation)

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but works fine. Thank you very much.

Comment: you are quite welcome.

Comment: Nice answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

[**yRead3**](http://www.spacejock.com/yRead3.html) is another good product.